# Using search and replace on URL query string

Tags: regex, vba

So my company rebuilt their entire intranet, and since they're not implementing 301 redirects, there are now loads of invalid links in company Word documents.

I have created a macro but need help with the regex so that I can find links of the format:

```
http://foo/bar/baz.php?id=string1:string2:string3:string4
```

and replace them with:

```
https://abc/def/ghi/string1/string2/string3/string4.aspx
```

Note that string2, string3 and string4 are not always present.

**My attempt**

search: `http://foo/bar/baz.php\?id=([\w]*):?([\w]*):?([\w]*):?([\w]*)`
replace: `https://abc/def/ghi/$1/$2/$3/$4.aspx`

The issue with this is that if string2, string3 or string4 aren't present, I end up with something like http://abc/def/ghi/string1///.aspx

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me. You don't have to use VBA regex in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply grab the whole `string1:string2:...` section, and replace the colons with slashes, put it in the url format you want, and append `.aspx`.  So, your main regex would then just grab the query string after `?id=`:

```
http://foo/bar/baz.php\?id=(.*)
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of how it can be done without a regex in VBA:

```
Sub replace_url()
Dim s As String, known As String, repl As String, res As String
s = "http://foo/bar/baz.php?id=string1:string2:string3:string4"
known = "http://foo/bar/baz.php?id="
repl = "https://abc/def/ghi/" '$1/$2/$3/$4.aspx

If Left(s, Len(known)) = known Then ' if the string starts with known substring
  Dim chunks() As String
  chunks = Split(Mid(s, Len(known) + 1), ":")
  res = repl & Join(chunks, "/") & ".aspx"
End If

End Sub
```

The main point here is that we have a known starting substring `http://foo/bar/baz.php?id=`. We check if the string in question starts with it, then get the rest of it and split with `:`. Then, just build the result by joining the array with `/` and appending `.aspx`.

Comment: I need the flexibility that a regex solution provides, but it's cool to see that VBA is powerful enough that you don't need to use it. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The power of regex is knowing when not to use it. I telling you that being a gold Regex badge holder on SO.